# problems with rt3070

Tags: wireless, 13.10, kernel

I have worked on this looking at other people's question regarding this with no success.

what I want to do is install the drivers for a USB wifi reciever. I downloaded the drivers from [Mediatek.com](http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downloads/01_windows.php?sn=501)

And I downloaded the 5th one down because it included the rt3070. After downloaded it, unpacked it in my desktop and then changed the `wpa` stuff to make it visable in the network connections(not my problem). Then I made it made install and then when I went to `modprobe rt3070` it said not found.

But there was rt5572 and successfully added it. I went and connected it and could use the internet. Then linux crashed. Something about kernal panic not in sync.

Am I sopposed to make a `rt3070.ko` and if so how ?

Because it only makes `5572.ko`

Please help any tips would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0):

looks like I got the new driver working now.  I had forgot to change the config.mk file to `HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y` & `HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y`

I also disabled ipv6.

Since I am using a 30ft powered usb cable, I also did a `sudo ifconfig wlan0 txqueuelen 675`.